# Can I run a 50 amp circuit underground?

Tags: electrical, wiring, underground

I need to run a 50 amp circuit (120/240V) from a shed to a travel trailer that is permanently in place.

The previous trailer had 30 amp 120V service running underground to a mounted/covered outlet under the trailer and then the standard trailer cable/plug into that.

The run is ~50 ft.  Running the 30 amp 120V service was fairly straightforward (big box hardware stores have the right wired for burying).  But when I start looking at 50 amp things get less straightforward (to me).

I'm assuming from a brief googling of big box stores have not resulted in any results for #6 non-conduit buriable wire.  So this leads me to believe that I need to run it in conduit, but then I get concerned about heat (this may be an incorrect understanding).

We only occupy the travel trailer 2 - 3 days a week for May/Jun/Jul/Aug/Sept.  Most of the days are spent outside and the AC & oven will rarely be used. (I understand that you should plan for the largest load not smallest).

Can I run 50 amp (120/240V) underground?  Do I need to ground the chassis of the trailer to a 8ft grounding rod?  Should I use #4 instead of #6 to reduce the heat concern?

Comment: Both [Lowes](http://www.lowes.com/pd_70404-295-14782703_0__?productId=3345390), and [Home Depot](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Southwire-6-3-UF-B-W-G-By-the-Foot-14782799/204632163?#.UkredIZwqvM) advertise 6/3 UF cable, though Lowes seems to only sell it by the foot. Are you asking how to run the cable, or where you can buy it?

Comment: At $4 per foot, you won't want to buy a lot of extra "just in case".  Measure carefully at least three times.

Comment: Thank you all.  It is so obvious on their pages now.  Not sure how I missed it.  $4/foot is crazy, but I understand why.  Thanks much.

Comment: Aluminum is usually far cheaper than copper.

Comment: Get a 50A - 30A dog bone and keep using your existing circuit.

Comment: If you go through the trouble of digging a trench for this new wire, bury several conduits instead of burying wire directly. You can then use them for a fresh water line, a sewer line out of a macerator, an additional circuit, telephone, ethernet, compressed air, etc.

Comment: @JayBazuzi Wouldn't it be dangerous to run it through a dogbone?  If I could keep the 30W circuit & breaker for now, I could do the rest in the spring when the ground is all muddy.  Won't be used until April more that 2 days.

Comment: There's no special danger. If something is mis-wired you might have trouble, but that's true of all electrical systems.

You won't be able to run more than 1 AC at a time. http://www.amazon.com/Camco-55185-Powergrip-Dogbone-Electrical/dp/B000BUQOGI/

Comment: Four bucks a foot?  NO, try $1.25.  If you must use 6/3 UF, get it at a proper electrical supply for closer to $2.30/ft.  Also consider URD 2-2-2-4 - which is wild overkill, but you can't beat the price at $1.25... aluminum is ideal for these large wire gauges.  http://www.wireandcabletogo.com/2-2-2-4-Dyke-Underground-Secondary-Distribution-Cable.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Cable

The cable you're looking for is Type UF, or Underground Feeder cable.

[image]

It can be purchased at [big orange](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Southwire-6-3-UF-B-W-G-By-the-Foot-14782799/204632163?#.UkriIoZwqvN), and [big blue](http://www.lowes.com/pd_70404-295-14782703_0__?productId=3345390), by the foot. It's available in 6/2, 6/2 with ground, 6/3, and 6/3 with ground, and is rated for direct burial.

## Attachment to Service

There is one temporary, and two permanent ways to supply power to a park trailer.

### Temporary

#### Power-Supply Cord

You'll want to use a NEMA 14-50 receptacle, and 4 wire cord with NEMA 14-50 plug to connect the trailer to the service.  The trailer's electrical grounding will be through the service plug, so only the distribution panel will have to be grounded.

[image]

### Permanent

#### Mast Weatherhead

You can use four continuously insulated, color-coded feeder conductors strung from a mast to a weatherhead as a permanent feeder.

[image]

#### Raceway

A metal raceway, rigid nonmetallic conduit, or liquidtight flexible nonmetallic conduit, from the disconnecting means to a junction box on the underside of the trailer can serve as a pathway to run permanently attached feeders.

[image]

## NEC

For reference, park trailers are covered in article 552 of the National Electrical Code.

Comment: Thank you.  It is so obvious on their pages now.  Not sure how I missed it.  $4/foot is crazy, but I understand why.  Thanks much.

Comment: If the cable is buried does it need to also be in conduit?

Comment: @TheEvilGreebo No.

Comment: At what depth must it be buried?

Comment: @TheEvilGreebo That's beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: @TheEvilGreebo If you need more questions answered, please deposit another $0.25.

Comment: Dang, you worked it out

Comment: When you run it underground, it's a good idea to also bury a marker several inches above it (often a red poly tape that says something like "CAUTION: Buried electric line below"). This helps prevent anyone who is digging from hitting it. You also need to use conduit above the minimum burial depth including when it's above ground.

Comment: @Tester101 I'm confused - I thought some regions require conduit no matter how deep the line is buried and even if it's UF. That's not the case?

Comment: @MikeB I can't keep up with every local change to the NEC, I simply go by the unmodified version.  It's possible that some locations may require this or that.

Comment: Some locations will also request that you put a couple inches of concrete over it but I believe this also depends on how deep it is buried.